# Writing String Data to a file (Overwrite if already exists and create new if not exists)

Tags: php, file-io

I want to write the content of a string variable say $data

in to a file named data.xml
the folder location will vary depends upon the content of $appId variable

like i want to write file in

```
  files_dir/$appId/data.xml
```

moreover if that file already exists than i want to rewrite otherwise i want to create the folder 
and then create the file data.xml

Can u suggest some way to do so.

Comment: [google: PHP Writing String Data to a file](http://www.google.com/search?q=PHP+Writing+String+Data+to+a+file)

Comment: possible duplicate of **[4,000-ish other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%2Bfile+%2Bwrite)** ... well, give or take.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write into a file in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768894/how-to-write-into-a-file-in-php)

Comment: Geez there are at least 5 different ways to do this in PHP, do some Google searching or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open file with write mode "w". will attempt to create file if does not exists otherwise truncate the file to zero length.

```
$handle = fopen("files_dir/$appId/data.xml", "w");
```

> Open for writing only; place the file
>   pointer at the beginning of the file
>   and truncate the file to zero length.
>   If the file does not exist, attempt to
>   create it.

You could check if the directory exists

```
if (!is_dir("files_dir/$appId")) mkdir("files_dir/$appId",0777);
$handle = fopen("files_dir/$appId/data.xml", "w");
```

Give the full path of directory and files.

Comment: should i use mkdir($appId, 0777); this also to create directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file_put_contents()` to write to the file : http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

And you can use `mkdir()` to create the folder portion : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php