# How to call a PHP file from HTML or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've looked around for a long while now and I can't find anywhere that answers this seemingly basic question. I don't care if the page reloads or displays the results immediately; I just want to have a button on my website make a PHP file run. That's it. And I've found that all websites either tell you how to run the PHP code in your HTML directly or tell you to use ajax. I'll use ajax if it turns out to be necessary, but there was a time before ajax existed that PHP was used, so I think there's a simpler way. If I can write the code inside HTML just fine, why can't I just reference the file for it in there or make a simple call for it in Javascript?

If it does turn out that ajax is the only way forward, what do I need to know about it to call a PHP file that will create a text file on a button press? I'm making a simple blog site for myself and I've got the code for the site and the javascript that can take the post I write in a `textarea` and display it immediately. I just want to link it to a PHP file that will create the permanent blog post on the server so that when I reload the page, the post is still there.

Thanks for taking the time to read and answer.

Comment: ever heard of $.ajax()

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow. Please take some time to read this guide before posting questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: If you want to avoid AJAX, use an iFrame

Comment: Read about HTML forms, that's it.

Comment: You're creating a blog site using text files for storage... you might want to look into PHP's database extensions

Comment: Why not just make the html page a .php page and stop trying to figure out how to do something that should be easier than you're making it?

Comment: not off-topic at all! Quite unfair closing this very interesting question.

Answer (score 65):

---

### How to make a button call PHP?

> I don't care if the page reloads or displays the results immediately;

Good!

*Note*: If you don't want to refresh the page see "*Ok... but how do I Use Ajax anyway?*" below.

> I just want to have a button on my website make a PHP file run.

That can be done with a form with a single button:

```
<form action="">
  <input type="submit" value="my button"/>
</form>
```

> That's it.

Pretty much. Also note that there are cases where ajax is really the way to go.

That depends on what you want. In general terms you only need ajax when you want to avoid realoading the page. Still you have said that you don't care about that.

---

### Why I cannot call PHP directly from JavaScript?

> If I can write the code inside HTML just fine, why can't I just reference the file for it in there or make a simple call for it in Javascript?

Because the PHP code is not in the `HTML just fine`. That's an illusion created by the way most server side scripting languages works (including PHP, JSP, and ASP). That code only exists on the server, and it is no reachable form the client (the browser) without a remote call of some sort.

You can see evidence of this if you ask your browser to show the source code of the page. There you will not see the PHP code, that is because the PHP code is not send to the client, therefore it cannot be executed from the client. That's why you need to do a remote call to be able to have the client trigger the execution of PHP code.

If you don't use a form (as shown above) you can do that remote call from JavaScript with a little thing called *Ajax*. You may also want to consider if what you want to do in PHP can be done directly in JavaScript.

---

### How to call *another* PHP file?

Use a form to do the call. You can have it to direct the user to a particlar file:

```
<form action="myphpfile.php">
  <input type="submit" value="click on me!">
</form>
```

The user will end up in the page `myphpfile.php`. To make it work for the current page, set action to an empty string (which is what I did in the example I gave you early).

> I just want to link it to a PHP file that will create the permanent blog post on the server so that when I reload the page, the post is still there.

You want to make an operation on the server, you should make your form have the fields you need (even if `type="hidden"` and use `POST`):

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" value="default value, you can edit it" name="myfield">
  <input type="submit" value = "post">
</form>
```

---

> What do I need to know about it to call a PHP file that will create a text file on a button press?

see: [**How to write into a file in PHP**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768894/how-to-write-into-a-file-in-php).

---

### How do you recieve the data from the POST in the server?

I'm glad you ask... Since you are a <strike>newb</strike> begginer, I'll give you a little template you can follow:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
    {
        //Ok we got a POST, probably from a FORM, read from $_POST.
        var_dump($_PSOT); //Use this to see what info we got!
    }
    else
    {
       //You could assume you got a GET
       var_dump($_GET); //Use this to see what info we got!
    }
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <meta char-set="utf-8">
     <title>Page title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <form action="" method="POST">
       <input type="text" value="default value, you can edit it" name="myfield">
       <input type="submit" value = "post">
     </form>
   </body>
 </html>
```

*Note:* you can remove `var_dump`, it is just for debugging purposes.

---

### How do I...

I know the next stage, you will be asking how to:

1. **how to pass variables form a PHP file to another?**
2. **how to remember the user / make a login?**
3. **how to avoid that anoying message the appears when you reload the page?**

There is a single answer for that: Sessions.

I'll give a more extensive template for [Post-Redirect-Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
    {
        var_dump($_PSOT);
        //Do stuff...
        //Write results to session
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['stuff'] = $something;
        //You can store stuff such as the user ID, so you can remeember him.
        //redirect:
        header('Location: ', true, 303);
        //The redirection will cause the browser to request with GET
        //The results of the operation are in the session variable
        //It has empty location because we are redirecting to the same page
        //Otherwise use `header('Location: anotherpage.php', true, 303);`
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        //You could assume you got a GET
        var_dump($_GET); //Use this to see what info we got!
        //Get stuff from session
        session_start();
        if (array_key_exists('stuff', $_SESSION))
        {
           $something = $_SESSION['stuff'];
           //we got stuff
           //later use present the results of the operation to the user.
        }
        //clear stuff from session:
        unset($_SESSION['stuff']);
        //set headers
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
        //This header is telling the browser what are we sending.
        //And it says we are sending HTML in UTF-8 encoding
    }
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta char-set="utf-8">
    <title>Page title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php if (isset($something)){ echo '<span>'.$something.'</span>'}?>;
    <form action="" method="POST">
      <input type="text" value="default value, you can edit it" name="myfield">
      <input type="submit" value = "post">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please look at php.net for any function call you don't recognize. Also - if you don't have already - get a good tutorial on HTML5.

Also, use UTF-8 [because UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Advantages_and_disadvantages)!

---

**Notes**:

> I'm making a simple blog site for myself and I've got the code for the site and the javascript that can take the post I write in a textarea and display it immediately.

If are you using a CMS (Codepress, Joomla, Drupal... etc)? That make put some contraints on how you got to do things.

Also, if you are using a framework, you should look at their documentation or ask at their forum/mailing list/discussion page/contact or try to ask the authors.

---

### Ok... but how do I Use Ajax anyway?

Well... Ajax is made easy by some JavaScript libraries. Since you are a begginer, I'll recomend [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

So, let's send something to the server via Ajax with jQuery, I'll use [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) instead of [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for this example.

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
    {
        var_dump($_PSOT);
        header('Location: ', true, 303);
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        var_dump($_GET);
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    }
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta char-set="utf-8">
    <title>Page title</title>
    <script>
        function ajaxmagic()
        {
            $.post(                             //call the server
                "test.php",                     //At this url
                {
                    field: "value",
                    name: "John"
                }                               //And send this data to it
            ).done(                             //And when it's done
                function(data)
                {
                    $('#fromAjax').html(data);  //Update here with the response
                }
            );
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value = "use ajax", onclick="ajaxmagic()">
    <span id="fromAjax"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above code will send a POST request to the page `test.php`.

*Note*: You can mix `sessions` with `ajax` and stuff if you want.

---

### How do I...

1. [**How do I connect to the database?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507230/mysql-connect-on-php/13508200#13508200)
2. [**How do I prevent SQL injection?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496)
3. [**Why shouldn't I use Mysql_* functions?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189)

... for these or any other, please make another questions. That's too much for this one.

Comment: Your answer should be moved to StackTutorial :D

Answer (score 2):

> I just want to have a button on my website make a PHP file run

```
<form action="my.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Generally speaking, however, unless you are sending new data to the server to be stored, you would just use a link.

```
<a href="my.php">run php</a>
```

(Although you should use link text that describes what happens from the user's point of view, not the servers)

---

> I'm making a simple blog site for myself and I've got the code for the site and the javascript that can take the post I write in a textarea and display it immediately. I just want to link it to a PHP file that will create the permanent blog post on the server so that when I reload the page, the post is still there.

This is tricker.

First, you do need to use a form and POST (since you are sending data to be stored).

Then you need to store the data somewhere. This is normally done using a database. Read up on the PDO library for PHP. It is the standard way to interact with databases.

Then you need to pull the data back out again. The simplest approach here is to use the query string to pass the primary key for the database row with the entry you wish to display.

```
<a href="showBlogEntry.php?entry_id=123">...</a>
```

Make sure you also read up on SQL injection and XSS.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already stated in your question you have more than one option. A very basic approach would be using the  tag referencing your PHP file in the method attribute. However as esoteric as it may sound AJAX is a more complete approach. Considering that an AJAX call (in combination with jQuery) can be as simple as:

```
$.post("yourfile.php", {data : "This can be as long as you want"});
```

And you get a more flexible solution, for example triggering a function after the server request is completed. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to post the form data to the insert php file function, see below :)

```
class DbConnect
{
// Database login vars
private $dbHostname = '';
private $dbDatabase = '';
private $dbUsername = '';
private $dbPassword = '';
public $db = null;

public function connect()
{

    try
    {
        $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->dbHostname.";dbname=".$this->dbDatabase, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword);
        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "It seems there was an error.  Please refresh your browser and try again. ".$e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function store($email)
{
    $stm = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO subscribers (email) VALUES ?');
    $stm->bindValue(1, $email);

    return $stm->execute();
}
}
```