# PHP function post with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP function that looks like this:

```
addPhone('859080', '111111111');
```

How can I call that function, from JavaScript, using AJAX, when I select a specific field on the form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: See: [How to call a PHP file from HTML or Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637944/how-to-call-a-php-file-from-html-or-javascript/20639432#20639432)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to make this work like this:

You HTML goes like this:

```
<button id="addPhone" data-phone="9999999999">
    Add Phone 9999999999
</button>
```

You JS (jQuery) goes like this:

```
$('#addPhone').on('click', function(e) {

    phone = $(this).data('phone');
    addPhone(phone);

});

function addPhone(phone) {

    $.ajax({
    url: "url_to_php_function",
    type: 'json',
    data: {
        'phone': phone
    },
    success: function(data){
      // You can access response here in data variable
    },
    failure: function(data){
      // handle errors here
    }
  });

}
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Thank you for the comment. So in what part exactly in your code is the function addPhone being called? 

SHould it be under the data?

Comment: OK thanks! ALso, nowhere do you have the other field from the funciton. The 859080

Comment: What does `addPhone()` does from your understanding

Comment: Currenly addPhone(), the PHP function, is an API call to add a phone number (11111111) to the contact (859080)

Comment: You should read about server side scripting and client-side scripting. I think you are miss-understanding these 2....I've updated the answer