# PHP write string data to a file

Tags: php

How can I write data to a file with PHP?

Here is an example of what needs to be written:

```
    $filename = 'test.txt';
    $keysize = '2048';
    $dname = 'www.domain.com';
```

The end result of the test.txt file should look like this

```
[ req ]
bits = 2048
domain_name = www.domain.com
```

Comment: Use `file_put_contents`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP write file from input to txt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998961/php-write-file-from-input-to-txt)

Comment: Since my last comment was removed I have to say it this way: `We can only give you links, but at the end you have to read/learn it! We can't learn for you!`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write into a file in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768894/how-to-write-into-a-file-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`file_put_contents`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
$output = "[ req ] \nbits = $keysize\ndomain_name = $dname";
file_put_contents($filename, $output);
```

`\n` makes a new line. I can put `$keysize` etc in the string itself because I'm using `"` to make the string - it would not work with `'`. See this relevant SO question: [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3446216/4799121)

Answer (score -1):

PHP Script is:

```
<?php
$output = "[ req ]"."<br>";
$output .= "bits = ".$keysize."<br>";
$output .= "domain_name = ".$dname."<br>";
$handle = fopen($filename , 'w');
$write =  fwrite($handle, $output);
fclose($handle);
?>
```

Comment: This will literally write `<br>` to the file, not a new line as OP wants