# How to create write to an existing text file using PHP?

Tags: php, android, http, text

I have an `Android` application that posts `String` data to a `PHP` file on my server.

I am using a simple PHP `GET` to retrieve the data, but currently am not doing anything with it:

```
<?php
  $stringUploaded = $_GET['stringFromAndroid'];


?>
```

I would like the data that I receive to be entered into a `text file`, also on the server.

What is the best way for me to do this?

Comment: [file-put-contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) is a good way, always check documentation/google for the default best approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend for you to use the `fwrite()`-method

The PHP Code:

```
$file= fopen(yourFile.txt, "w");
fwrite($file, $stringUploaded);
fclose($file);
```

This should work :)

Comment: Thanks, what is the difference between this and file_put_contents ?

Comment: @java123999 according to this  [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20100109103851/http://balancedbraces.com/2008/06/12/fopen-fwrite-fclose-vs-file_put_contents/) fwrite is slightly faster

Comment: OK thanks, will this keep the file open so that I can send data from my Android app (e.g. every 10 seconds) and the php GET method will process it and send it to the text file?

Comment: with `fopen()` you open the file, as long as you dont call the `fclose()`-Method you can do as many `fwrite()`as you wish, but you have to remember to not use the parameter "w" in `fopen()` because it would clear everthing in the file. use `"a"` instead :)

Comment: Do you think that file_put_contents would be a better approach?

Comment: i've never worked with `file_puts_contents()` so i dunno what would be better, the only difference is just the speed, but thats not really noticable

Comment: @java123999 oh and pick an answer as the most useful one, so if anyone comes back on this topic they know the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: just for future reference - this is a PHP question, don't mark it as Android, as it's irrelevant.

TL;DR: [Here is a relevant answer from a different topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768894/how-to-write-into-a-file-in-php)

Long answer:

You should really specify your PHP version, but  to give you a generic answer, you can either use a general-purpose function like `fopen` + `fwrite` and `fclose` or a special function like `file_put_contents($filename, $content)`.

Update:
**It's a good practice to write code in the most explicit way possible**, so that the next person can understand it quickly. If your intent is to dump some data in a text file, use file_put_contents, and you will make the said intent explicit. Performance-wise it's the exact same thing - check [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: Thanks, will keep it in mind, which method would you suggest?

Comment: I need to keep the file open so that I can send data from my Android app (e.g. every 10 seconds) and the php GET method will process it and send it to the text file?

Comment: It's a good practice to write code in the most explicit way possible, so that the next person can understand it quickly. If your intent is to dump some data in a text file, use `file_put_contents`, and you will make the said intent explicit. Performance-wise it's the exact same thing - check http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: `I need to keep the file open so that I can send data from my Android app (e.g. every 10 seconds) and the php GET method will process it and send it to the text file?`

This will not work - assuming that you are using a standard LAMP stack with Apache or something similar, PHP scripts are executed on each request - read, executed, closed, so you cant' share an open file between requests.

Comment: Anyway, you probably don't want to write to a file directly anyway. Check a simple local database like [sqlite](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_php.htm)