# Output from New York Time API to JSON file

Tags: php, json

I am a complete noob when working with APIs and PHP. 
I want to have the following code dump results into a file called **books.json**
and I have no idea how to do it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
// Built by LucyBot. www.lucybot.com
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$query = array(
  "api-key" => "MY APRI KEY"
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,
  "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/lists/best-sellers/history.json" . "?" . http_build_query($query)
);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Sorry I downvote because it seems you made no effort in at least searching for resources on how to open and write a file in PHP.

Comment: Has already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768894/how-to-write-into-a-file-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at file_put_contents:

```
file_put_contents($path_to_file, $result);
```

Comment: Thanks. file_put_contents is creating the file, but it is blank. Am I missing something?  <?php
// Built by LucyBot. www.lucybot.com
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$query = array(
  "api-key" => "MY KEY"
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,
  "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/lists/best-sellers/history.json" . "?" . http_build_query($query)
);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
json_encode($result);
file_put_contents("books2.json", $result);
?>